# How to block/prevent deleting a Chrome (for Windows) Profile?

Tags: windows, google-chrome

(Not sure which of the two sites is best to post this, so I am trying both. If this is inappropriate, please advise.)
see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77286244/how-to-block-prevent-deleting-a-chrome-profile

I'm trying to prevent the ability to delete a Chrome profile.

My thinking is to block/prevent opening the Chrome (for Windows) Profile Picker.

I use a browser extension (LeechBlock, though this is not key) that can allow blocking the new Chrome Profile Picker main window via the addressbar, by using a regular expression ^chrome://profile-picker.

The problem is you can still access the profile picker if you select/click the profile icon then select/click the gear icon for "Manage Profiles", or click the three dots, highlight the user profile icon, and select/click "Manager Other Profiles" in the submenu; in both cases this brings up a separate pop-up window for the Profile Picker, but it lacks the addressbar.

Does anyone know how to determine the addressbar reference for this window, or some other means to block this pop-up window?

Or any other ideas on how to prevent deleting a profile?

(Using Chrome for Windows).

P.S. I am only using and only have admin access to consumer level Windows, not Pro, Enterprise, Educational, etc.)

Comment: [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/)

Comment: The closest "solution" I have found is found in a reply here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/77184659/8884051  I am looking for a viable FREE option (not into paying a subscription for a single trick solution). BUT it gives a clue, because it seems to be making a regex entry. Can anyone identify what regex entry can be made to prevent Chrome from opening a window based on its title?

Comment: Another approach would be if someone can point out how to know the URL for the pop-up Profile-Picker window.

Answer (score 1):

If the user has access to that Chrome browser profile to *use* it, then the user has access, [using Windows Explorer](https://www.howtogeek.com/255653/how-to-find-your-chrome-profile-folder-on-windows-mac-and-linux/), to `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default` to modify or delete it. It would be pointless to block only *Chrome*, if the user can use Windows Explorer, or the CMD prompt, to change the profile.

More effective at *keeping* that profile, and far simpler, is to periodically make backup**s** (plural) of that profile to another location. There are [File History](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-automatically-backup-files-folders-on-windows-10-computer), [Scheduled Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17996936/batchfile-to-create-backup-and-rename-with-timestamp), and [third-party tools](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/free-imaging-backup-recovery-software-windows) to do so.

However, I'd recommend going a step further: make periodic **drive images**. That not only protects that profile, but also all data, programs and the operating system. Were a drive to fail (inevitable, over time), or the PC to be hacked, one could restore *everything* in the last image to a new drive.

An alternative is to run in very-much incapacitated [Windows Kiosk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-single-app) mode. "The person using the kiosk cannot do anything on the device outside of the kiosk app." Then it might make sense to block the user *within* Chrome browser from changing the profile.

Comment: I am after a preventative solution, so backup is nice but does not achieve my goal. Windows Kiosk might be nice but is limited to one app, which does not serve my purposes, as there needs to be access to multiple apps.  Thanks for pointing out access via File Explorer or CMD prompt. I can block access to the CMD prompt and I have a tool that can block access to the Chrome User Data folder. I have not implemented this, so need to test that it does not interfere with Chrome writing inside that folder. (For those interested, it is a freemium app called AskAdmin).

Comment: If someone can point out how to know the URL for the pop-up Profile-Picker window, that would be a start.